# Android Unique ID on Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a project that takes Device ID from a user device to prevent user's accounts being hacked, but Expo.Constants.deviceId are dynamic, means every time user kills the app, the Device ID will be refreshed. My question is how can I get a static unique ID that won't be refresh every time user kills the app?